# HTK Installation on Ubuntu make all not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, voice-recognition, htk

I have tried several times to compile and install HTK but I just can't get through Step 5!
When executing "make install" (after "make all" executed correctly) I get the following output:

```
root@Humanoid:/bin/htk# make install
(cd HTKTools && make all) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/bin/htk/HTKTools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/bin/htk/HTKTools'
(cd HTKTools && make install) \
    || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/bin/htk/HTKTools'
if [ ! -d /usr/local/bin ] ; then mkdir /usr/local/bin ; fi
for program in HSLab HBuild HCompV HCopy HDMan HERest HHEd HInit HLEd     HList HLRescore             
HLStats HMMIRest HParse HQuant HRest HResults HSGen HSmooth HVite  ; do /usr/bin/install -    
c -m 755 ${program} /usr/local/bin ; done
make[1]: Leaving directory `/bin/htk/HTKTools'
(cd HLMTools && make all) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/bin/htk/HLMTools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/bin/htk/HLMTools'
(cd HLMTools && make install) \
    || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/bin/htk/HLMTools'
for program in Cluster HLMCopy LAdapt LBuild LFoF LGCopy LGList LGPrep LLink LMerge     
LNewMap LNorm LPlex LSubset  ; do /usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ${program} /usr/local/bin ;     
done
make[1]: Leaving directory `/bin/htk/HLMTools'
```

I just don't know what to do and there isn't nothing on the net.
Does anyone have any ideas how I can install HTK?

```
My OS Details are:
OS: ubuntu 13.04
OS type: 64-bit
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) II Dual-Core M300x2
```

Comment: Whatever you were attempting to install seems to have been installed in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Comment: So... what's the problem?  I don't see any error here.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Yes you are right, the question was: shouldn't happen anything? Because in the output it only says "Nothing to be done for `all'.". I thought there were problems.

Comment: I followed this tutorial: http://www.voxforge.org/home/dev/acousticmodels/linux/create/htkjulius/tutorial/download    and the problem is that at the when I execute "julian" to know if it installed correctly, it says "command not found". Therefore I thought the problem was in that output.

Comment: [SOLVED]I just had to install some libs: http://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk

Comment: answer your own question properly and accept the answer in case anyone has the same problem in the future

Comment: yeah. please add detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answered in the comments. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> [SOLVED]I just had to install some libs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk